# How to get the photo from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, upload, photo

I have a photo id "2296309061879" and it work perfectly in 
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2296309061879

I use the Graph API link:
https://graph.facebook.com/2296309061879
get false as ALWAYS......
How about it work with my Access Token generated in my application that create by myself immediately?

https://graph.facebook.com/2296309061879?access_token=AAABnQBRA8V0BAF6Idy3ZBXD0As7kEt3ogZCp5yZB435MaZBVZCUV8xZCawgoHewciScXWDdMuiBk5sIWZCI1uJM64H3oWAl6eenZBlSutDwB9D5sT3kahRcK

still get false as ALWAYS......

So, how to get the photo from facebook with the photo id?

Another serious problem is, I use facebook's api to upload a photo to my account, and it return me the photo id. then I goto my facebook to check the photo: it does not exist in any album!!

What's wrong with facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your app doesn't have rights to access it.

This is a public photo from my facebook:

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2651141672758

It also returns `false` if I try to use https://graph.facebook.com/2651141672758

If I try it in the explorer I also get `false`:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=2651141672758

If I click on the "get access token" button, and select the `user_photos` permission ... it then works.

**Edit:** Note the first set of bullet points in the Graph API docs for photos: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/ - It would appear they're wrong, or there's a bug currently as it states *any*  valid access token should be able to see public images and that's demonstrably not working. In order for the explorer app to list my albums and/or photos I have to explicitly grant it the `user_photos` permission